# ¿ Como crear menú desplegable automático?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de que el menú desplegable aparezca automáticamente cuando pasemos el ratón por encima.
He visto un ejemplo en la comunidad con jQuery pero no consigo adaptarlo a mi ejemplo.
Otro problema es que tengo estilos en un archivo ("css/bootstrap.min.css"), la versión Bootstrap v3.3.5 y veo que no se muestra la barra de navegación donde esta el desplegable: (SOBRE MI).
En mi proyecto funciona el desplegable pinchando en el, aquí no, pero no se como enlazar los archivos bootstrap para que puedan ver lo que he conseguido hasta el momento, y puedan ayudarme con el desplegable automatico.
Gracias.

```js
// Offset for Site Navigation
$('#siteNav').affix({
 offset: {
  top: 100
 }
})
/*script para despliegue automatico*/
    $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
// hover in
$( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').show("slow");
  }, function() {
// hover out
var menuHover = !$(this).next(".dropdown-menu").is(":hover");
if (menuHover) {
  $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').hide("slow");     
}
  }
);

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).prev().is(":hover")) {
$(this).hide("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: yellowgreen;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: forestgreen;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url('http://i64.tinypic.com/11j9dad.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px 70px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

 header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
     font-size: 100px;
  }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.section-heading {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.intro {
 color: #fff;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    padding: 70px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.content-2 {
 color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.content-3 {
 padding: 20px 0 40px;
 text-align: center;
}

.promo,
.promo h3,
.promo a:link,
.promo a:visited,
.promo a:hover,
.promo a:active {
    color: white;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.promo-item {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
}

.promo-item:hover {
    background-size: 110%; 
    border: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    line-height: 160px;
}

.promo-item h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.item-1 {
 background: url('../images/writing.jpg');
 }
 
.item-2 {
 background: url('../images/concert.jpg');
 }
 
.item-3 {
 background: url('../images/pencil_sharpener.jpg');
 }
  
.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 }

.page-footer {
 text-align: center;
 }

.page-footer .contact {
 padding: 100px 0;
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: #fff;
 }

.page-footer .contact p {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 300;
 }
 
.content-3 .glyphicon, 
.page-footer .contact .glyphicon {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: 700;
 }
  
.page-footer .small-print {
 padding: 50px 0 40px;
 font-weight: 300;
 }

.text-light {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

.navbar-default {
    border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: yellowgreen!important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
        letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
        border-color: #fff;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: yellowgreen;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #eb3812;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: #222;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: yellowgreen;
    }
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    border-color: #eee;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-default .badge {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.btn-primary {
    border-color: yellowgreen;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    border-color: limegreen;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: limegreen;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
    border-color: yellowgreen;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
    color: yellowgreen;
    background-color: #fff;
}


.btn {
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-lg {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

img::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

.text-primary {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

.bg-primary {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Template by Quackit.com -->
<!--  Imágenes de diversas fuentes bajo la licencia Creative Commons CC0 y / o la licencia Creative Commons Zero.
Aunque puede usarlos, para un sitio web más exclusivo, reemplace estas imágenes por las suyas.-->
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--  -Las 3 metaetiquetas anteriores * deben * ser lo primero en la cabeza; cualquier otro contenido principal debe venir * después * de estas etiquetas-->

    <title>Principal</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS personalizado: puede usar esta hoja de estilo para anular cualquier estilo de Bootstrap y / o aplicar sus propios estilos -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim y Respond.js Compatibilidad con IE8 de elementos HTML5 y consultas de medios -->
    <!-- ADVERTENCIA: Respond.js no funciona si ves la página a través de un archivo:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fuentes personalizadas de Google-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    

    <script>
        $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
    // hover in
    $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').show("slow");
  }, function() {
    // hover out
    var menuHover = !$(this).next(".dropdown-menu").is(":hover");
    if (menuHover) {
      $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').hide("slow");     
    }
  }
);

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).prev().is(":hover")) {
$(this).hide("slow");
  }
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navegación-->
    <nav id="siteNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                 LOGO
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="Principal.html">CASA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">RECURSOS</a>
                    </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
       <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.es/maps/place/Calle+del+Olivar,+5,+05400+La+Parra,+%C3%81vila/@40.224582,-5.0602472,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd40756225aeabbd:0xcc0228cc3c4de2c8!8m2!3d40.2245779!4d-5.0580585?hl=es">UBICACION</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

 <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="header-content-inner">
                <h1>CONTACTE CONMIGO</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
     <!-- Intro Section -->
        <section class="intro">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="font-size: 60px"></span>-->
                        <h2 class="section-heading">Le hacemos una auditoría gratuita para ver lo que más se adapta a su negocio.</h2>
                        <p class="text-light">Hacemos seguimiento del funcionamiento de su aplicación y corregimos lo que usted desee.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Custom Javascript -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque no hacés la prueba de colocar la función en el nav donde esta:

```
<nav id="siteNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

quedando:

```
<nav id="siteNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" **data-spy="affix"** **data-offset-top="100"**>
```

Comment: hola. No entiendo,

Comment: ,Perfecto, funciona a la perfeccion . Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Buenas amigo no se si es lo que buscas pero funciona a la perfección lo unico que tienes que hacer es comentar la función

```
/*$('#siteNav').affix({
   offset: {
    top: 100
  }
})*/
```

Que te da el **error** espero te ayude saludos, Para observar el funcionamiento agranda el ejemplo.

```js
// Offset for Site Navigation
/*$('#siteNav').affix({
 offset: {
  top: 100
 }
})*/
/*script para despliegue automatico*/
    $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
// hover in
$( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').show("slow");
  }, function() {
// hover out
var menuHover = !$(this).next(".dropdown-menu").is(":hover");
if (menuHover) {
  $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').hide("slow");     
}
  }
);

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).prev().is(":hover")) {
$(this).hide("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: yellowgreen;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: forestgreen;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url('http://i64.tinypic.com/11j9dad.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px 70px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

 header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
     font-size: 100px;
  }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.section-heading {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.intro {
 color: #fff;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    padding: 70px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.content-2 {
 color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.content-3 {
 padding: 20px 0 40px;
 text-align: center;
}

.promo,
.promo h3,
.promo a:link,
.promo a:visited,
.promo a:hover,
.promo a:active {
    color: white;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.promo-item {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
}

.promo-item:hover {
    background-size: 110%; 
    border: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    line-height: 160px;
}

.promo-item h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.item-1 {
 background: url('../images/writing.jpg');
 }
 
.item-2 {
 background: url('../images/concert.jpg');
 }
 
.item-3 {
 background: url('../images/pencil_sharpener.jpg');
 }
  
.item-1,
.item-2,
.item-3 {
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 }

.page-footer {
 text-align: center;
 }

.page-footer .contact {
 padding: 100px 0;
 background-color: yellowgreen;
 color: #fff;
 }

.page-footer .contact p {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 300;
 }
 
.content-3 .glyphicon, 
.page-footer .contact .glyphicon {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: 700;
 }
  
.page-footer .small-print {
 padding: 50px 0 40px;
 font-weight: 300;
 }

.text-light {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

.navbar-default {
    border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: yellowgreen!important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
        letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
        border-color: #fff;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: yellowgreen;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #eb3812;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: #222;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: yellowgreen;
    }
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    border-color: #eee;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-default .badge {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.btn-primary {
    border-color: yellowgreen;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    border-color: limegreen;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: limegreen;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
    border-color: yellowgreen;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
    color: yellowgreen;
    background-color: #fff;
}


.btn {
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-lg {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

img::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

.text-primary {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

.bg-primary {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Template by Quackit.com -->
<!--  Imágenes de diversas fuentes bajo la licencia Creative Commons CC0 y / o la licencia Creative Commons Zero.
Aunque puede usarlos, para un sitio web más exclusivo, reemplace estas imágenes por las suyas.-->
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--  -Las 3 metaetiquetas anteriores * deben * ser lo primero en la cabeza; cualquier otro contenido principal debe venir * después * de estas etiquetas-->

    <title>Principal</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS personalizado: puede usar esta hoja de estilo para anular cualquier estilo de Bootstrap y / o aplicar sus propios estilos -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim y Respond.js Compatibilidad con IE8 de elementos HTML5 y consultas de medios -->
    <!-- ADVERTENCIA: Respond.js no funciona si ves la página a través de un archivo:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fuentes personalizadas de Google-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    

    <script>
        $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
    // hover in
    $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').show("slow");
  }, function() {
    // hover out
    var menuHover = !$(this).next(".dropdown-menu").is(":hover");
    if (menuHover) {
      $( this ).next('.dropdown-menu').hide("slow");     
    }
  }
);

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
  if (!$(this).prev().is(":hover")) {
$(this).hide("slow");
  }
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navegación-->
    <nav id="siteNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                 LOGO
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="Principal.html">CASA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">RECURSOS</a>
                    </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
       <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.es/maps/place/Calle+del+Olivar,+5,+05400+La+Parra,+%C3%81vila/@40.224582,-5.0602472,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd40756225aeabbd:0xcc0228cc3c4de2c8!8m2!3d40.2245779!4d-5.0580585?hl=es">UBICACION</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

 <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="header-content-inner">
                <h1>CONTACTE CONMIGO</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
     <!-- Intro Section -->
        <section class="intro">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="font-size: 60px"></span>-->
                        <h2 class="section-heading">Le hacemos una auditoría gratuita para ver lo que más se adapta a su negocio.</h2>
                        <p class="text-light">Hacemos seguimiento del funcionamiento de su aplicación y corregimos lo que usted desee.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Custom Javascript -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias compañero. Quitando esa funcion resulta, pero me quita un efecto que la imagen cubre la barra de navegacion y al hacer scrool se muestra la barra de otro color. Aqui no se muestra por que falta el archivo "css/bootstrap.min.css", que es Bootstrap v3.3.5, y al ser muy largo no le puedo poner. Si quieres trato de poner el bootstrap.min.css en css para que lo veas, pero seguro que no me permite tanto codigo. Espero haberme explicado, encima que intentas ayudar no quiero liarte ...Gracias.

Comment: bueno amigo cuando tengas un problema de css usa el inspector del browser y revisa ese elemento y la clase que le agrega esa propiedad que esta dando problemas en este caso es el color saludos

Comment: Gracias, ya preguntare....